# LibGDX not running render() method

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm experiencing a problem using LibGDX.

I have a `Screen` and in its `render` method I have:

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen{
private OrthographicCamera guiCam;
private TankChallenge tankChallenge;
private SpriteBatch batcher;
private GL10 OpenGL;

public LoadingScreen(TankChallenge tankChallenge) {
    this.tankChallenge=tankChallenge;
    Gdx.graphics.setTitle("RobotChallange Beta - Loading");

    float AR = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    guiCam = new OrthographicCamera(10,10 * AR);
    guiCam.position.set(10f/2,AR*10f/2,0);
    batcher = new SpriteBatch();

    OpenGL = Gdx.graphics.getGL10();
    //loadAssets();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    OpenGL.glClearColor(1, 0.5f, 1, 1);
    OpenGL.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    System.out.print("e");
    guiCam.update();
    Sprite sp = new Sprite();
    sp.setColor(1f,1f,0, 1);
    sp.setSize(100,100);
    sp.setOrigin(20, 0);

    batcher.setProjectionMatrix(guiCam.combined);
    batcher.begin();
    batcher.disableBlending();
    sp.draw(batcher);
    batcher.end();
}
```

I call this by setting it in the implementes `ApplicationListener` class. I know it is arriving the LoadingScreen because Title is actually set to "RobotChallenge Beta - Loading".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a solution for both problems. I added to the Game extending class this:

```
public void render() {
    super.render();
}
```

Thanks to this the problem is solved and I don't need to override the SetScreen method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after setting this as your screen, you need to call `super.render()` in your `Game` extending class. For instance, I use the following method in my main `Game` extending class for setting the screen:

```
@Override
public void setScreen(Screen screen)
{
    super.setScreen(screen);
    super.render();
}
```

This seems to kick off `render()` being called.

Comment: This solved the problem of render not being called. Now I'm experiencing a problem I think I should ask in another topic. I see flicker or blinking when rendering.

If I put this in the render: OpenGL.glClearColor(1, 0.5f, 1, 1); OpenGL.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); I see the screen blinking all the time from pulple to black over and over.

Comment: And I have a System.out.print("e"); And the output is only one "e". I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry I don't know about the flickering, I haven't used libgdx in a long time, I just remember `render()` not firing for me and having a lot of trouble fixing it and fished out my old code from the forgotten depths of my projects folder.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'll ask in another topic since it is 0-related to this one.

Comment: The problem is actually that thanks to your fix the render method is called only once... I have a print in the render in the LoadingScreen's render() and it is only shown once...

Comment: I found a solution for both problems. I added to the Game extending class this:  public void render() { 
  super.render();
 }

Thanks to this the problem is solved and I don't need to override the SetScreen method. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved it! If I remember rightly you shouldn't need to do that, but as long as it works and isn't a dirty hack then it's all good! Might be an idea to post that as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove @Override render() in your Game extending class, that fixes the problem. Overriding setScreen method causes flickering you mentioned.